# Swift3 - how to call class or struct functions by name

Tags: swift3

As I come from a JS background this is how I'd call a function by name stored in a variable:

```
var obj = {
    foobar: function(param) {
        // do something
    }
};

var key = "foobar";

obj[key](123);
```

Now I would like to recreate this in Swift, for example:

```
struct obj = {
    func foobar(param) {
        // do something
    }
}

let key:String = "foobar"

obj[key](123)
```

The above code unfortunately gives `Type 'obj.Type' has no subscript members`

Is there any way to call functions by names in a Struct, Class or a Dictionary (if it's even possible to store functions in Dicts?)

**EDIT - MORE CONTEXT:**

I have a user-supplied array of things say:

```
let arr = ["apples", "oranges", "pears"]
```

but this array can be as long as 20 items. Based on each item of the array I need to perform certain action. So I iterate over the array:

```
for (key, _) in arr {
    if (key == "apples") {
        handleApples()
    }

    if (key == "oranges") {
        handleOranges()
    }

    // and so on...
}
```

Sure, I can have a function with a simple `switch` that would consist of 20 cases but that's far from ideal. What if my array grows to say 100 items?

I was hoping to achieve something similar to this:

```
for (key, _) in arr {
    myClass[key]()
}
```

Comment: It is not possible because all variable / function names are evaluated at compile time.

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve? There's almost certainly a better of solving it than using strings to call methods.

Comment: @Hamish I've edited my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way to call functions by names in a Struct, Class or a Dictionary (if it's even possible to store functions in Dicts?)

### Yes you can store a function into a dictionary

Let's define a function type

```
typealias FuncType = () -> ()
```

and 2 functions

```
func func0() {
    print("Apples")
}

func func1() {
    print("Oranges")
}
```

Now we can create a dictionary where the key is `String` and the value is `FuncType`

```
let dict : [String:FuncType] = [
    "Apples" : func0,
    "Oranges" : func1
]
```

And of course we can invoke a function stored into the dictionary

```
dict["Apples"]?() // prints "Apples"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be what you're looking for:

```
var obj: [String: Int] = {
  // do something, like call foobar(param) that's defined outside of the variable
  // or just manipulate data directly in here

  return ["foobar": 123]
  // or whatever dictionary you want that matches the type you defined for obj
}()
```

Kind of tough to give you a better answer without you posting the kind of output or behavior you're looking for.